# Android App Development - Theme Trouble

Tags: android, themes

My first question :-)
So recently I took up app development, and was going through the tutorial posted here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

I finished part 1 - "Building Your First App" and followed exactly every instruction.

According to the Google tutorial, the result should look like:
http://developer.android.com/images/training/firstapp/firstapp.png

However, when I ran the app using the emulator (Platform 4.2.2, API level 17), the app was missing the theme, meaning only the black bar with the app icon and a white background.

I don't know what is wrong, when I created the application (project), I made sure to set the theme to "Holo Light with Dark Action Bar" as instructed in the tutorial.
Is it because I am running the app in the emulator? If not, then what do you think I should do to fix the issue?

Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I ran the app using the emulator (Platform 4.2.2, API
>   level 17), the app was missing the theme, meaning only the black bar
>   with the app icon and a white background.

`Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` is a light theme with a dark ActionBar, so your app does not look wrong. If you want a dark theme, then use `Theme.Holo`.